Why my fragment not observe change of livvedata in view model
i have a live data(isEquipmentTabEnabled) in a view model. i update it in fragment1 and i observe it in fragment2.
when i call update this from fragment1, update method in viewmodel call but then change not observe in fragment2. this is my code:
//Update
i log a visibility of fragment1 and its not visible.
i think my problem is use of viewpager
i shorted the code and i observe correctly it in fragment1 but i not observe it in fragment 2
My View Model:
class NetworkDisadvantageVm @Inject constructor(
    var applicationn: Application,
    var networkDisadvantageManager: NetworkDisadvantageManager,
    var goodsItemManager: GoodsItemManager,
    var gson: Gson
) : BaseVm(applicationn) {
    private var isEquipmentTabEnabled = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)

    val getIsEquipmentTabEnabled: MutableLiveData<Boolean>
        get() = isEquipmentTabEnabled

    fun updateIsEquipmentTab(condition: Boolean) {
        isEquipmentTabEnabled.value = condition
    }

   

    override fun handleUserAction(action: String, data: Any) {
        when (action) {
            
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val ACTION_UPDATE_NETWORK_DISADVANAGE = "ACTION_UPDATE_NETWORK_DISADVANAGE"
        const val ACTION_ERROR_UPDATE_NETWORK_DISADVANAGE = "ACTION_ERROR_UPDATE_NETWORK_DISADVANAGE"

    }
}
my fragment 1:

class NetWorkDisadvantageDetailFragment : BaseFragment() {
private var _binding: NabNetworkDisadvantageFragmentBinding? = null
private lateinit var mNetWorkDisadvantageViewModel: NetworkDisadvantageVm
private lateinit var mission: Mission
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mNetWorkDisadvantageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, mViewModelFactory)
        .get(NetworkDisadvantageVm::class.java)
  
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = NabNetworkDisadvantageFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root

    binding.datetext.text = GeneralUtil.convertPersianDate(GeneralUtil.Now())
    binding.datetext.tag = GeneralUtil.getDateFormat().format(GeneralUtil.Now())*/
    binding.takenAction.setOnClickListener { onRadioButtonClicked(it) }
    binding.inProgressReferTo.setOnClickListener { onRadioButtonClicked(it) }
    binding.tempActionReferTo.setOnClickListener { onRadioButtonClicked(it) }
    binding.CustomerAbsence.setOnClickListener { onRadioButtonClicked(it) }
    binding.notSeen.setOnClickListener { onRadioButtonClicked(it) }
    binding.wrongAddressNoActionTaken.setOnClickListener { onRadioButtonClicked(it) }
    return view

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    mNetWorkDisadvantageViewModel.getIsEquipmentTabEnabled.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { isEnabled ->
        Log.e("test","tet")
    }
    
}

private val binding get() = _binding!!

private fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View) {
    val checked = (view as RadioButton).isChecked

    // Check which RadioButton was clicked and deselect others
    when (view.id) {
        binding.takenAction.id -> {
            if (checked) {
                mNetWorkDisadvantageViewModel.updateIsEquipmentTab(true)
                binding.inProgressReferTo.isChecked = false
               

            }
        }

        binding.inProgressReferTo.id -> {

            if (checked) {
                mNetWorkDisadvantageViewModel.updateIsEquipmentTab(false)
                binding.notSeen.isChecked = false
                
                // Handle other RadioButton selections here
            }
        }

        binding.tempActionReferTo.id -> {
            if (checked) {
                mNetWorkDisadvantageViewModel.updateIsEquipmentTab(false)

                binding.inProgressReferTo.isChecked = false
               

            }
        }

        binding.CustomerAbsence.id -> {
            if (checked) {
                mNetWorkDisadvantageViewModel.updateIsEquipmentTab(false)

                binding.takenAction.isChecked = false
               
                // Handle other RadioButton selections here
            }
        }

        binding.notSeen.id -> {
            if (checked) {
                mNetWorkDisadvantageViewModel.updateIsEquipmentTab(false)

                binding.inProgressReferTo.isChecked = false
                

            }
        }

        binding.wrongAddressNoActionTaken.id -> {
            if (checked) {
                mNetWorkDisadvantageViewModel.updateIsEquipmentTab(false)

                binding.takenAction.isChecked = false
                binding.tempActionReferTo.isChecked = false
                binding.inProgressReferTo.isChecked = false
                binding.CustomerAbsence.isChecked = false
                binding.notSeen.isChecked = false
                // Handle other RadioButton selections here
            }
        }

    }
}

companion object {
    fun newInstance(mission: Mission) = NetWorkDisadvantageDetailFragment().apply {
        this.mission = mission
    }
}

}
and this is my fragment 2:
class NetworkDisadvantageFragment: BaseFullScreenDialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var mViewModel: NetworkDisadvantageVm
    private var _binding: NabTabLayoutBinding? = null
    private lateinit var mission: Mission

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, mViewModelFactory)
            .get(NetworkDisadvantageVm::class.java)
     
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = NabTabLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        val networkDisadvantage= NetWorkDisadvantageDetailFragment.newInstance(mission)
        val goodsItem= GoodsItemFragment.newInstance(mission)
        val title = listOf("اجناس", "فرم اقدام")
        val frgs = listOf(goodsItem, networkDisadvantage)
        val adaptor= FragmentAdaptor(requireActivity(),
        frgs as List<Fragment>, title
        )
            binding.viewPager.adapter = adaptor
        binding.viewPager.currentItem = 2
        TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = title[position]
        }.attach()
      
        

        return view

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mViewModel.getIsEquipmentTabEnabled.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { isEnabled ->
            val tabStrip = binding.tabLayout.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
            val tabView = tabStrip.getChildAt(0)
            tabView.isEnabled = isEnabled
            tabView.isClickable = isEnabled
        }
    }


    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    companion object{
        fun newInstance(mission: Mission) = NetworkDisadvantageFragment().apply {
            this.mission = mission
        }
    }
}


and this is view model provider:
package com.edsab.takrim.injection.component

@Subcomponent
interface ViewModelSubComponent {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): ViewModelSubComponent
    }
    
    fun NetworkDisadvantageVm(): NetworkDisadvantageVm
    fun NetWorkDisadvantageDetailVm(): NetWorkDisadvantageDetailVm

}


@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(viewModelSubComponent: ViewModelSubComponent) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private val creators: ArrayMap<Class<*>, Callable<out ViewModel>> = ArrayMap()

    init {
        // View models cannot be injected directly because they won't be bound to the owner's
        // view model scope.
       
        creators[NetworkDisadvantageVm::class.java] = Callable { viewModelSubComponent.NetworkDisadvantageVm() }
        creators[NetWorkDisadvantageDetailVm::class.java] = Callable { viewModelSubComponent.NetWorkDisadvantageDetailVm() }

    }

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        var creator = creators.get(modelClass)
        if (creator == null) {

            creators.forEach { entry ->
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.key)) {
                    creator = entry.value
                }

            }

        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown model class $modelClass")
        }
        try {
            return creator?.call() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }
}

i log state of fragment and state of its is resumed. and  when i debug LiveData java class i see that observer is empty list!
i want My fragment observe change of viewmodel live data.
how can i fix it?
EDIT:
I found solotion with that i should set reuireactivity()this in this line at two fragment:
 mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, mViewModelFactory)
            .get(NetworkDisadvantageVm::class.java)

change to
 mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity(), mViewModelFactory)
            .get(NetworkDisadvantageVm::class.java)

is these right way to handle it?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

I have trimed it
